# Setup code for xibs in iOS. -awakFromNb:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIImageView which I placed in interface builder and set to a custom class I have created `SASImageView` . However, when the view is loaded I want to do some setup so I have placed code in `awakFromNib` however, this does not seem to be called.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

[image: I set the the custom class to be SASImageView which is a subclass of UIImageView]

How would I do some setup for this view in code, after its been loaded from interface builder?

Thanks.

Comment: Try putting it in the `initWithCoder:` method

Comment: No problem. I posted it as an answer with more specific information as well for future reference if you'd like to accept it.

Comment: probably because you don't init the class from a `nib`. try to use (maybe!) the `–didMoveToSuperview` method, alternatively. in most of the cases that method can be a good place to set up a designable view.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can easily put in the `initWithCoder:` method since you're loading from an XIB file:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        //Add customizations here
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Sidenote: Setting `numberOfTapsRequired` to `1` is unnecessary, as that's the default.